# Define piecewise function with automatic broadcasting in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a function with a form similar to `f` below.

```
function f(x, y)
    if x <= y
        return x + y
    else
        return x - y
    end
end
```

I would like to modify it so that it can accept mixed scalars and vectors such that `f(1, 2) = 3` and `f([1, 4], 2) = [3, 2]`. What would be the simplest way to achieve that which also maintains its nice Latexify.jl output?
[image: nice Latexify.jl output]

Attempts:

- Broadcasting at the call site works, but I'd rather handle it here in the definition.
- `@. if x <= y` yields an error since `if([1,0])` doesn't work.
- I thought of using an array comprehension, but then that would never return a scalar.

Comment: turn it into a kernel that defines elementwise semantics, then let whatever executes the kernel handle broadcasting (or make a wrapper function for that). kernel definition will probably look pretty when clad in latex.

Comment: Imho, broadcasting at call site is exactly what you should do. What's the problem with it? It also has the advantage that's it's automatically independent from the concrete array type.

Comment: I'm not sure what a kernel is; I have only heard that term in relation to Linux. Is that a Julia solution?

Well `@.` works very conveniently for automatic broadcasting of my non-`if` functions. I was hoping there was something similar that would still work through `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalars broadcast with themselves so you can just define the function to broadcast unconditionally.

```
f(x, y) = ifelse.(x .<= y, x .+ y, x .- y)

@show f(1, 2) f([1, 4], 2) f(2, [1, 4]) f([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

```
f(1, 2) = 3
f([1, 4], 2) = [3, 2]
f(2, [1, 4]) = [1, 6]
f([1, 2], [3, 4]) = [4, 6]
```

Alternatively, if you really need the pretty LaTeX, you can just define two functions:

```
using Latexify
tex = @latexrun g(x, y) = x < y ? x + y : x - y
f(x, y) = g.(x, y)
tex
```

```
L"$g\left( x, y \right) = \begin{cases}
x + y & \text{if } \left( x < y \right)\\
x - y & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$"
```

Comment: I knew there must be something! `ifelse.` is the piece I was missing. Thank you for the alternative LaTeX answer also.